# I have a problem precompile the Flux package in Julia

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am trying to add Flux into my package repository in Julia but I am getting an error.

I typed pkg> add Flux but Julia REPL returns "5 dependencies errored".

And they are:

1. LLVM
2. GPUCompiler
3. CUDA
4. NNlibCUDA
5. Flux

To see a full report either run `import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()` or load the packages
I ran the command precompile and this is what i got.

```
ERROR: The following 1 direct dependency failed to precompile:
Flux [587475ba-b771-5e3f-ad9e-33799f191a9c]
Failed to precompile Flux [587475ba-b771-5e3f-ad9e-33799f191a9c] to 
C:\Users\Kostas\.julia\compiled\v1.6\Flux\jl_3C4D.tmp.
ERROR: LoadError: could not load library "C:\Users\Kostas\.julia\juliaup\julia- 
1.6.4+0~x64\bin\LLVM.dll"
The specified module could not be found.
Stacktrace:
[1] dlopen
  @ .\libdl.jl:114 [inlined]
[2] #dlopen#2
  @ .\libdl.jl:110 [inlined]
[3] dlopen (repeats 2 times)
  @ .\libdl.jl:110 [inlined]
[4] loaded_llvm()
  @ LLVM.API C:\Users\Kostas\.julia\packages\LLVM\shuW4\src\LLVM.jl:49
[5] top-level scope
  @ C:\Users\Kostas\.julia\packages\LLVM\shuW4\src\LLVM.jl:60
[6] top-level scope (repeats 2 times)
  @ none:1
```

Any ideas how can i fix this and use Flux properly?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, and it looks like your Julia install is broken - someone else had a similar issue on Julia 1.5 here: https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl/issues/681. What OS are you on and how did you install Julia? Why are you using Julia 1.6.4 (latest stable release is 1.7.1)?

Comment: I downloaded Julia from Microsft Store and i just update Julia to 1.7.1 version and i have the same problem. Should I just delete them all and dowload julia again ? My OS is Windows 11 Home 21H2

Comment: Yes I would probably try to nuke everything (the folder where Julia is installed by the Windows store, as well as your `Users\Kostas\.julia` folder and do a clean install of 1.7.1. from the website. If that works there might be a problem with the Windows store installation.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.